# sql forwarding queries to teradata?

Tags: sql, sql-server, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

Is it possible to forward a query from sql server to teradata so that the query is counted from teradata resources?

Comment: `OPENQUERY` to a linked Teradata server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As dnoeth mentioned, a linked server to Teradata will be the best bet. You can access it several ways, including the use of OPENQUERY but also 4 part names, etc.

Teradata provide some instructions on setting it up here: https://downloads.teradata.com/blog/netfx/2011/12/setup-sql-server-2008-r2-linked-server-to-the-teradata-database

If you get stuck, just ask back, but that looks pretty straightforward.